# Does JAXB support xsd:restriction?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jaxb, xsd-validation

```
<xs:element name="age">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
      <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
      <xs:maxInclusive value="120"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

So I want it to get converted to Java code like this:

```
public void setAge(int age){
    if(age < 0 || age > 120){
         //throw some exception
    }
     //setting the age as it is a valid value
}
```

Is it possible in JAXB?

Had seen some WebService Client stub generator doing this maybe axis2 webservice but not sure.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) specification does not cover generating fail fast logic into the domain model.  A common practice now is to express validation rules in the form of annotations (or XML) and run validation on them.  [**Bean Validation (JSR-303)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303) standardizes this and is available in any Java EE 6 implementation.

**XJC Extensions**

I have not tried the following extension myself but it appears as though it will generate [**Bean Validation (JSR-303)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303) annotations onto the domain model representation validation rules from the XML schema. As XJC is very extensible there may be other plug-ins available as well.

- https://github.com/krasa/krasa-jaxb-tools

Comment: Thanks and there is one more thing. There is a [http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-917] JIRA for JAXB Facets, this is not included in JSR for JAXB. Right? Is this some standard implementation of some other standard?

Comment: @NarendraPathai - This is the first I've heard of JAXB Facets.  This is currently not part of the JSR and is being proposed as an enhancement to the JAXB reference implementation.  I have posted a comment on the JIRA issue asking about it's compatibility with Bean Validation (JSR-303).  A JSR-303 compatible approach would be something that could be supported in a future version of the JAXB specification.

Comment: Thanks Blaise. I follow your blogs and would love to hear about some implementation of this in JAXB.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan - What's the status of this?

Answer (score 5):

The suggested way to perform this validation in JAXB is switching on schema validation on the marshaller resp. unmarshaller:

```
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI); 
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(...);

ValidationEventHandler valHandler = new ValidationEventHandler() {
  public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
      ...
  }
};

marshaller.setSchema(schema);
marshaller.setEventHandler(valHandler);
```

Comment: I know but if the schema contains xsd:restriction then the generated code does not reflect those constraints

Comment: Ok, in JAXB standard and RI there are no such mechanisms. I guess they are not used since not all schema constraints can be validated immediately (for example "minOccurs=2").

Comment: but as I have mentioned in the question have seen some axis tools generating classes which utilize xs:restriction.

Comment: There used to be the verification plugin, but that is inactive for a long time. Maybe krasa-jaxb-tools comes close to what you are looking for. It generates validation annotations. I have to admit that I have not used it for real projects.

Answer (score 5):

You can try [JAXB-Facets](https://github.com/whummer/jaxb-facets). Quick snippet:

```java
class MyClass {

    @MinOccurs(1) @MaxOccurs(10)
    @Facets(minInclusive=-100, maxInclusive=100)
    public List<Integer> value;

    @Facets(pattern="[a-z][a-z0-9]{0,4}")
    public String name;

}
```