# Limit class property size

Tags: java

I'm looking for a way to limit the size of a class properties. Users can create new instances and I want to limit that some String property must have from n to m characters, or another Integer property must be a whole number from some range.

I haven't found any way to do this in the class definition, do I need to define my methods like:

```
public String checkInput (String input, int length) {
   if (input.length() > length) {
      return input.substring(0, length);
   } else return input;
}
```

Comment: There is **Input Validation** using annotations and some tooling. Like JAXB. Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775465/does-jaxb-support-xsdrestriction)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can throw this exception inside your `if` condition:

```
throw new InvalidParameterException(MessageFormat.format("Insufficient param {0}!", param)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could perform checks in the constructor, when the object is being instantiated.  And you could make the fields `final` so that the user cannot alter them after the constructor finishes.  Something like this:

```
public class yourClass {
    private final String data;

    public yourClass(String input) {
        data = input.substring(0, 100);
        // maybe log that the input is being truncated

        // or maybe throw new IllegalArgumentException
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    // no setter = data is immutable
}
```

In the example above, the string `data` is limited to a max size of only 100 characters.  You could also throw an exception from the constructor, if you want to block the object from being created from a too-large input.

Answer (score 0):

The OOP way: define your own class to express that type, like:

```
public abstract class LengthRestrictedString {
  abstract int getMaxLength(); 

  private final String content;
  protected LengthRestrictedString(String content) {
    if (content!=null) {
     if (content.length() > getMaxLength()) {
       throw some exception;
     }
     this.content = content;
```

And then you can create specific subclasses that implement that *abstract* method to give a specific length, like:

```
public class PropertyString extends LengthRestrictedString {
  @Override 
  final int getMaxLength() { return 25; }
  ... constructor
```

or something similar. Now you can use the class `PropertyString` in all places where you want/expect such length restricted strings.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for bean validation: https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/spec/#builtinconstraints
like @Min @Max for integer, @Pattern for strings